# DNS/Route53 - Configuring records and dealing with www

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I most likely have set up my DNS records incorrectly and I'm wondering how to do it properly. I receive an 'uknown host' message when I try ping `http://www.site.com/`, yet I can reach `www.site.com` and `site.com` via browser. (Noticed this when the Magento installation would give me errors telling me url is unreachable)

My records are:

```
site.com. A [Elastic IP]
site.com. NS [awsdns.co.uk, etc] 
www.site.com. A [Elastic IP]
```

I also have everything open to my IP in the security group.

---

Another question: Should I have either `www.site.com` or `site.com` redirect to the other instead of both going to the elastic IP? How should I do this if lets say I'd like `site.com` go to `www.site.com`?

Answer (score 2):

I presume you meant running `ping www.site.com` and *not* actually `ping http://www.site.com/`. The latter would obviously fail because ping expects a host name, not a URL.

In regards to handling www, the common way to do it is:

```
site.com.  A  [Elastic IP]
site.com.  NS [awsdns.co.uk, etc]
www.site.com.  CNAME site.com.
```

In any case, you do not have to do it that way as long as you update both occurrences of your IP when it changes.

Comment: Ah I see. Regarding the www. - the example you posted www.site.com leads to site.com, yes? If so, how can I have the other way around? I tried doing a basic switch but Route53 gives me "RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name site.com. is not permitted at apex in zone site.com." when I try to alter the site.com record. Also - any pitfalls in this approach?

Comment: The way I suggested only ensures that both `site.com` and `www.site.com` resolve to the same IP address. If you want redirect behaviour i.e. `site.com` -> `www.site.com` you have to do it in your web server. CNAME can't be configured the other way around, so the Route53 error message makes sense.